# Control file access in iis 7

Tags: iis, iis-7

I have a configuration xml file (config.xml) hosted in iis 7.  My flex app needs access, but I want to prevent users from browsing directly to it.

Is there a way to prevent users from directly browsing to the xml but still allow the flex app to read it?

Thanks!